# What type of environment is this?

Tags: identification, software

Do you know what type of environment is this? I didn't find any information on Google.

[image]

Comment: It appears to be an ALi development environment.

Comment: Do you actually have that software? If so, did you do "Help->About" or such?

Comment: Looks like a pretty hostile environment to me...

Comment: Thanks for replies answer. Im trying to figure out how firmware for Digital Satellite receiver is writen (Amiko Mini Combo is model). It has ALi 3612 chip inside it and I was told that I need to have that development environment. It is very strange that I could not find any informations about that environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALi used to be a chipset (and minor BIOS, IIRC) vendor. That looks like a Visual Studio 6 knock-off development environment (down to the icons -- compile, make, build, etc.), similar to AMI VeB (Visual eBIOS) -- I used that as a BIOS developer until very recently.

Probably used for low-level firmware / x86 software development would be my best guess. I know they built some embedded stuff back in the day that was 8051-based as well, could be supporting that.

Comment: Hello Krunal Desai, thanks for answer. Im trying to figure out how firmware for Digital Satellite receiver is writen (Amiko Mini Combo is model). It has ALi 3612 chip inside it and I was told that I need to have that development environment. It is very strange that I could not find any information about that environment.